# Bus error with SVD of large matrix in R 4.02

Tags: r, macos, matrix, runtime-error

I recently discovered that using the base SVD function on a large matrix (109865 x 414) was causing RStudio 1.3.1073 to crash (running R 4.0.2 on macOS 10.15.6 with 32GB RAM). Running the same code in terminal provided the following error:

> *** caught bus error *** address 0x1195ed000, cause 'non-existent
> physical address'
>
> Traceback:  1: La.svd(x, nu, nv)  2: svd(problemMatrix) An
> irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
>
> *** caught bus error *** address 0x11d604000, cause 'non-existent
> physical address'
>
> Traceback:  1: La.svd(x, nu, nv)  2: svd(problemMatrix) An
> irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
>
> *** caught segfault *** address 0x1297b9000, cause 'memory not
> mapped'

No error is given when performing SVD on a 109865 x 414 matrix of random values. Running the *same* code on the *same* original matrix on a different computer (running R 4.0.0 on macOS 10.15.4 with 8 GB RAM) performs the SVD as expected, without throwing an error. The newer R installation has otherwise been completely stable.

So, admittedly a sort of hyperspecific, potentially non-reproducible question, but any thoughts on what might be responsible for this error? Problematic matrix uploaded as an R data file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PNKG0_nrPvEboXcFIQj-CV39X3ZR1W4u/view?usp=sharing).

Thanks!

Comment: reproducible here. The worst part is that if prcomp is called identically a second time, it seems to work. This is a fresh homebrew install with no old packages

Comment: p.s. by identically a second time, I mean ignoring the choice after the segfault is caught with ctrl-C, which returns to the prompt (probably undefined behavior? but it seems to just work)

Answer (score 2):

This may have related to the homebrew installation of R. The code ran successfully after completely removing R and all packages and then reinstalling manually with the latest release from CRAN.